# Suppressing "Notice: Relation exists" when using "CREATE ... IF NOT EXISTS"

Tags: postgresql

I have a function that creates a temporary table to store and process data. Problem is I want to run this function on the order of 1M times within a single transaction, without having:

```
NOTICE:  relation "foo" already exists, skipping
```

output ~1M times. Is there an efficient way to do so?

**What is not efficient:**

1. Dropping the table instead

   ```
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS
   ```

   - Leads to running out of shared memory
2. Catching the duplicate_table exception (less efficient than using IF NOT EXISTS?)

   ```
   BEGIN
       CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo () ON COMMIT DROP;
   EXCEPTION
       WHEN duplicate_table THEN --do nothing
   END;
   ```

Comment: `set client_min_messages = ...`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHEN

Comment: Can that be temporarily configured?

Comment: Yes using the `set` command I mentioned

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the `client_min_messages` setting is what you want. There are a number of ways to configure this.

`SET client_min_messages = warning` or `SELECT set_config('client_min_messages', 'warning', false)` will persist for the rest of the current session/connection.

`SET LOCAL client_min_messages = warning` or `SELECT set_config('client_min_messages', 'warning', true)` resets at the end of the current transaction.

The `CREATE FUNCTION` statement's `SET` clause will scope the setting only to this function; this sounds like the most suitable option in your case. For example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f()
  RETURNS void
  SET client_min_messages = warning
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
  AS ...
```

Comment: "*will persist for the rest of the current session/connection.* - but only if the transaction is not rolled back. From the manual: "*If SET (or equivalently SET SESSION) is issued within a transaction that is later aborted, the effects of the SET command disappear when the transaction is rolled back*"

Comment: Actually that should be `SET client_min_messages = warning`. The message for `IF EXISTS` and `IF NOT EXISTS` is a notice level (lower then warning).

Answer (score 8):

Simply

```
SET client_min_messages = error;
```

before running the statement(s).

You can also set it on the `psql` command line for batch executions

```
PGOPTIONS="-c client_min_messages=error" psql -f somefile.sql dbname
```